# Количество слов в файле

Tags: c

Здраствуйте, написал код для нахождения всех слов в файле, но он не работает, подскажите, что не так

```
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int count;
    FILE *cfPtr;
    char  s[1000];
    if((cfPtr=fopen("lab31.txt", "r"))==NULL) {
        printf("Error"); 
    }

    count=0;
    while (!feof(cfPtr)) {
        fscanf(cfPtr,"%s", s);
        while(s[0]!=0) count++;
        s[0]='\0';
    }

    printf("Count = %d\n",count);
    fclose(cfPtr);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `while( s[0] != 0 )` этот цикл у вас бесконечен (к тому же непонятно что вообще этим хотите добиться)

Comment: Если отформатировать, то сразу видно, где и что.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 void main()
```

Ошибка 1 (не фатальная, но...), правильно:

```
int main(void)
```

Ошибка 2:

```
if( ( cfPtr = fopen( "lab31.txt", "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
    printf( "Error" );
}
```

Ну выведете вы "Error", и что? Мало того, что сообщение неинформативно, так ещё и программа не прекратится, а продолжит работать с нулевым `cfPtr`. Лучше так:

```
if( ( cfPtr = fopen( "lab312.txt", "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
    perror( "Can not open file 'lab31.txt'" );
    return -1;
}
```

А ещё лучше имя файла брать из аргументов программы.

Ошибка 3:

```
while (!feof(cfPtr)) {
```

`EOF` случится только при следующем неудачном вызове `scanf()`, но не до него. В результате одно лишнее выполнение тела цикла. В котором, к тому же, не проверяется результат `scanf()`. Правильней:

```
while( fscanf( cfPtr, "%s", s ) != EOF ) {
```

Ошибка 4:

```
while( s[0] != 0 )
    count++;
```

Что это такое и зачем я так и не понял. Но цикл заведомо бесконечный.

Итого:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    unsigned count = 0; /* всё-таки не int */
    FILE *cfPtr;
    char  s[1000];

    if( ( cfPtr = fopen( "lab31.txt", "r" ) ) == NULL ) {
        perror( "Can not open file 'lab31.txt'" );
        return -1;
    }

    while( fscanf( cfPtr, "%s", s ) != EOF ) {
        count++;
    }

    printf( "Words found: %u\n", count );
    fclose( cfPtr );
    return 0;
}
```

Но это ещё не всё. Как верно заметили в комментариях, если сами слова нам не нужны, то нет и никакой необходимости в буфере `s[1000]`, и цикл чтения файла можно упростить до:

```
while( fscanf( cfPtr, "%*s" ) != EOF ) {
    count++;
}
```

Как принять имя файла из аргументов программы, и что делать если длина слов будет больше `sizeof(s)` и сами слова зачем-то нужны - это уже самостоятельно :)

Comment: Поскольку слова нам совершенно ни к чему, нужно только их количество, я бы выбросил `char s[1000];`, а цикл `while` заменил на `while( fscanf( cfPtr, "%*s" ) != EOF ) {
        count++;
    }` - и никаких проблем с переполнением буфера за отсутствием такового :)

Comment: @Harry,  ага. Но кто знает зачем был тот загадочный цикл :)

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли, понял свои ошибки, еще и добавил условие, что числа не в счет) Еще раз вам спасибо)